# Show comment upvotes on activity tab

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page

Not sure if this would happen here or in the higher SE site, but I was wondering if would be possible to show comment votes when viewing comments we've left in the activity tab.

For example, I often go to my profile and click on the Activity sub-tab (now 'All Actions') to find comments I've recently left. If I want to see how many upvotes the comment got, or any responses (ones that don't tag me specifically), I have to click the comment and go to the question. Since comment "scores" don't affect reputation, I'm not aware of any other way to check them.

While I realize there's no easy way to show comments that follow (is there?), I think it would at least be possible to show the number of upvotes beside each comment, just like when viewing the question/answer on its own page. Granted, that's the least of the two uses but still. Seeing your comment get voted up is a great feeling if nothing else.

**Would this be a possible and/or useful feature to add?**

---

**META LINK:** [Display the Number of Comment Upvotes In Recent Activity Pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38285/288263)

Comment: It might be useful, but it's not a feature that's likely to be implemented solely for Sci-Fi:SE. As such, you'd probably be better raising it on Meta.StackExchange

Comment: StackExchange hates comments. Why would they possibly agree to make comment system better for users? :)

Comment: We're discussing it on the Meta and I put out a bounty on the request. Apparently I'm not the first to ask - the feature has been requested since 2010. If nothing else, someone posted a script add-on that will do it somewhat. I added a link to that discussion/question if anyone is interested.

Comment: I think that since, in intention, comments are meant to be temporary and for the express purpose of helping to improve a question or answer, following which they may become obsolete and deleted, this one is probably a "no".  I'm aware that this SE makes a somewhat broader use of comments than the norm however so maybe it's something that actually is more relevant to us in particular rather than to the general SE network.